# Google Plus when did I get a notification?

Tags: google-plus, notifications

Is there a way to learn the time of a notification?

For example, on Facebook, when someone comments on my status or tags me in some photo I receive an instant notification, and when I open my notification window it says *2 hours ago* or *a few seconds ago* etc.

Is there such a feature on G+ as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly if you're receiving email notifications you'll have a timestamp on the email message.

Some of the notifications (depending on what they are) do have a date/time on them. You may need to go to "View all notifications" to see that (or at least click the notification itself).

I think, though, that this isn't practical in G+. Notifications for the same item get rolled up into one notification record. (For instance, I see a notification on a post of mine telling me that three people have +1'd it and one person has shared it. Obviously they didn't all do it at the same precise moment.)

Comment: Thanks, I've received a +1 to my comment and I really wanted to know when did it happened. _guess I'll never know_